# In a scalar function on SQL Server, is the only form of flow control via If...Else?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, functions

In a scalar valued user-defined function on SQL Server 2019, is the only form of flow control the `If...Else` block?

Ideally I would rather use `CASE...END`, but everything I've found indicates this is not an option for flow-control, and only works to return a value in a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: T-SQL `CASE` is an expression, not a control flow statement. This differs from other programming languages.

Comment: Yes, you are correct of course. Sorry my terminology is incorrect.

Comment: I would ask what's your goal ultimately that you don't want to use `IF` / `ELSE`?...Are you trying to write your function in a way such that it's inline-able? If so, that's potentially possible without using `IF` / `ELSE` with a logical re-write, but would need to see the code.

Comment: Oh, it's a phone number cleanup function with some twists. There are multiple levels, and since there's no `ELSEIF`, they get nested with `ELSE...IF...ELSE`. And so it gets a little ugly to read for troubleshooting. If I could use `CASE...END`, it would be much cleaner.

Comment: Better question: why do you need a scalar function, why not use a Table Valued Function, which can be fully inlined and is much faster.

Comment: @spinjector Heads up for the future, make sure to use `@Username` when replying to someone, so they get notified. I only happened to pop back in and see your reply. FWIW, you probably should post the code with the rules, and someone could probably still offer a cleaner coded solution that's also more performant by making it inline-able like Charlieface and I mentioned. I've personally created performant phone number cleanup functions before.